# space between two tool buttons and hboxlayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I'm trying to remove two tool buttons and add the other widgets and add an hboxlayout using an even filter if the window is shown or hidden. 
The problem is when I remove the spacer the horizontal one, the two buttons are tied together successfully, but when I add a widget, there is a space between the tool button and the widget as shown in the figure. how would I remove that space ?

here is the initialization

```
    setWindowTitle(tr("Points of Interest"));
    m_splitter->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 3);
    m_gridLayout = new QGridLayout(this);

    m_gridLayout->addWidget(m_splitter, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    m_hBoxLayout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
    m_gridLayout->addLayout(m_hBoxLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiButton);
    m_hBoxLayout->addStretch();
    m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiFilterButton);
    m_gridLayout->setVerticalSpacing(0);
```

here is the code and the image:

[image]

```
if (event->type() == QEvent::Show)
    {
        if (obj == m_poiItemWidget)
        {
            bool visibleName = false, visibleHeight = false, visibleRange = false;
            visibleName = m_namePoiFilter.isVisible();
            visibleHeight = m_widgetHeight.isVisible();
            visibleRange = m_widgetRange.isVisible();




            m_namePoiFilter.setVisible(visibleName);
            m_widgetHeight.setVisible(visibleHeight);
            m_widgetRange.setVisible(visibleRange);

            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiButton);
            for (int i = 0; i < m_hBoxLayout->count(); ++i)
            {
                QSpacerItem *spacer = m_hBoxLayout->itemAt(i)->spacerItem();
                if (spacer)
                {
                    delete m_hBoxLayout->takeAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiFilterButton);
            m_hBoxLayout->addStretch();
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_namePoiFilter);
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_widgetHeight);
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_widgetRange);


        }
    }

    if (event->type() == QEvent::Hide)
    {
        if (obj == m_poiItemWidget)
        {
            bool visibleName = false, visibleHeight = false, visibleRange = false;
            visibleName = m_namePoiFilter.isVisible();
            visibleHeight = m_widgetHeight.isVisible();
            visibleRange = m_widgetRange.isVisible();



            m_namePoiFilter.setVisible(visibleName);
            m_widgetHeight.setVisible(visibleHeight);
            m_widgetRange.setVisible(visibleRange);
            for (int i = 0; i < m_hBoxLayout->count(); ++i)
            {
                QSpacerItem *spacer = m_hBoxLayout->itemAt(i)->spacerItem();
                if (spacer)
                {
                    delete m_hBoxLayout->takeAt(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiButton);
            m_hBoxLayout->addStretch();
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(m_myPoiFilterButton);
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_namePoiFilter);
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_widgetHeight);
            m_hBoxLayout->addWidget(&m_widgetRange);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in initialization

```
m_gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
m_hBoxLayout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Unfortuantely, this didn't solve the problem. There is still a space between the QToolbutton